# How can I stop a bouncing responsive page with mixed-height, one or two-column, Bootstrap Carousel items?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I have a simple Bootstrap Carousel at the top of a long page.  Items on the carousel are a mix of text and images and consequently are not always the same height.

This leads to a bouncing page below the carousel.  Can you help me figure out a way to keep the responsive layout and stop the bouncing text?  I'm getting sea sick!

The solution needs to solve the following:

1. Stop bouncing text below the carousel
2. Continue to allow the 2-column carousel items to be collapsed into 1-column when the responsive page is below a certain width (this means that the height of the carousel may very well double when viewed in a narrow window in one column)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PmZnh/1/

```
<h1>This is my carousel site</h1>
<hr>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
        <h2>List One</h2>
        <ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h2>List Two</h2>
        <ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li><li>Item 4</li><li>Item 5</li></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h2>List Three</h2>
        <ul><li>Item 1 is longer this time. Way longer than the first time. It just keeps going and going and going.</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li><li>Getting sea sick yet?</li></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
<hr>
<p>The rest of the text on the site shouldn't bounce and should be responsive-friendly!</p>
<p>1. the .items are flexible height (but usually within 10-20px)<br>
2. when the page width is below 760px the list shrinks from two columns to one column, meaning the height may now be twice as tall as before.</p>
```

Comment: And I'm aware that there are image solutions already on SO that basically fix the height of the image or `.item`. Unfortunately my situation isn't resolved as easily. I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a `min-height`to the carousel div:

```
#myCarousel{
    min-height: 180px;
}
```

If you have now problems, with the fact that the height of the div might be to high on certain viewports ajust them manually:

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
  #myCarousel{
    min-height: 130px;
  }
}

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { 
  #myCarousel{
    min-height: 140px;
  }
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
  #myCarousel{
    min-height: 180px;
  }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
  #myCarousel{
    min-height: 200px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This hit the spot.